# About an equivalent condition for convergence of a scalar series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

So I came across this problem a while back when one of my friends suggested it. The question asks to show that the scalar series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right)a_n$$ converges. The scalar field under consideration is real or complex. We were able to show the result holds if $a_n>0$. But the general case is eluding us.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: what kind of convergence? absolute convergence?

Comment: Conditional convergence I believe. We already proved for the terms being positive, so I guess that handles absolute convergence.

Comment: Could you please post how you proved the case for $a_n>0$, someone might be able to expand on that.

Comment: Yeah sure. For one side, assuming $\sum a_n$ is convergent, we observe that the bracket thing is smaller than $\pi^2/6$ and hence the series is dominated by $\sum (\pi^2/6)a_n$ and thus is finite and hence the original series converges.

For the other direction, we note that $24/\pi^2$ times the bracket thing is always greater than 1 and hence the series times $24/\pi^2$ dominates $\sum a_n$ and thus it converges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series has the form $\sum_n b_n a_n$ where $b_n \to b>0$ and $|b_n-b|<1/n^2$. Write $d_n=b_n-b$.

If $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then $|a_n|$ are bounded, so $\sum d_n a_n$ converges absolutely whence $\sum_n b_n a_n=\sum (ba_n + d_n a_n)$ also converges.

If $\sum_n b_n a_n$ converges, then the summands are bounded, so $|a_n|$ are also bounded.  Therefore $\sum d_n a_n$ converges absolutely whence
$$\sum ba_n =\sum (b_n a_n - d_n a_n)$$ also converges.